# Does an Iranian with German residency need a visa to enter Romania?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, romania, iranian-citizens, german-residents

I am from Iran but I study and live in Germany now. Do I need to apply for visa to participate in a conference being held in Romania?

Comment: I study in Germany too. And I recently visited Romania with my Schengen residence permit for a couple of days. No issues!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ir&DE=ro&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=de&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Germany for a maximum stay of 90 days

So no, you do **not** Need a visa; at the border just present your passport and residence permit

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you don't need to get a visa if you fall into one of the categories listed below:

> **Holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas
>   or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States.**
>
> Starting July 11, 2014, in keeping with the provisions of Decision No
>   565/2014/EU, Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own
>   national visas, for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of
>   180 days the following:
>
> - The two or multiple entry short-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The limited territorial validity visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The short-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The long-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The long-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The residence permit issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia
> - The long-term resident's EC residence permit (the validity of which is of 5 years or more) issued by a member state of the European Union.

*Source: [Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://mae.ro/en/node/2040)*